# Why if I set an object to a new variable it saves initial value of the variable?

Tags: javascript

I found some strange behaviour of JavaScript with passing variables as a parameter to function, here is the snippet:

```
var notWorks = {
    aa: "string",
}

function why() {
    var thisWorks = notWorks;
    $.get("/echo/json").then(function() {
        printVal(notWorks);
        printVal(thisWorks);
    });
    notWorks = {};
}

function printVal(val) {
    console.log(val);
}
why();
```

The output is:

```
Object {  }
Object { aa: "string" }
```

With variable notWorks everything is clear - function in then() is called when the variable is already cleared. But why if I set this object to a new variable it saves initial value of the variable? Object is passing to fuction by link, doesn't it?

Fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/cev8m79y/

Comment: Your title is like you're scolding JavaScript. :-)

Comment: The problem is that `$.get` is asynchronous.

Comment: you'll need a promise to wait for the async call to come back then run the function

Comment: My mistake, it **isn't** a duplicate of [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: @ntgCleaner that is exactly what the `.then` does. It just needs to be pointed out its asynchronous, as always with these issues :) Note: No parameters were passed in the calling of these functions (apart from the resource path string, but lets ignore that for the sake of a pop-culture reference).

Comment: @somethinghere, Ah thanks, I didn't see the `.then`

Comment: This question has ZERO to do with async.

Comment: @George No, it has absolutely NOTHING to do with async. It's about the order in which statements are executed, but the "problem" observed by the OP does not need async calls in any way, shape or form.

Comment: if I pass global object to **printVal** it takes actual value of the object on that moment - empty object, it's OK for me.
But if I just assign this object to a new variable and then pass it to **printVal** it somehow prints initial value instead of empty object
So, what the difference between these two calls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Javascript pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> With variable `notWorks` everything is clear - function in `then()` is called when the variable is already cleared.

Yes.

> But why if I set this object to a new variable it saves initial value of the variable? Object is passing to fuction by link, doesn't it?

This line:

```
var thisWorks = notWorks;
```

copies the *reference* to the object from `notWorks` to `thisWorks`. There is no ongoing connection between the *variables* at that point, they just both refer to the same object.

Then you start the `get`, and set `notWorks` to refer to a new, blank object. `thisWorks` still refers to the previous object. So when the `get` completes later and you log both of them, you see that `thisWorks` still points to the original object and `notWorks` still points to the new, blank object.

Let's throw some ASCII-Art at it (okay, technically it's Unicode-Art):

We start with this:

```
notWorks: Ref11232−−−+
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     |  |   (object)   |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−>| aa: "string" |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

(The "Ref11232" is just a placeholder for the value of the object reference. We never actually see the value of an object reference, but you can think of it as a number that tells the JavaScript engine where the object is in memory.)

Then in `why`, you create a new variable, `thisWorks`, via `var thisWorks`:

```
notWorks: Ref11232−−−+
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−>|   (object)   |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        | aa: "string" |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
thisWorks: undefined
```

And you set it to the same value as `notWorks` via `thisWorks = notWorks`:

```
notWorks: Ref11232−−−+
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−>|   (object)   |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     |  | aa: "string" |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     |
thisWorks: Ref11232−−+
```

Now they both point to the same object.

Then you start `get`, which has no effect on those variables or objects at all.

Then you give `notWorks` a new value:

```
notWorks: Ref84325−−−+
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−>|   (object)   |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        |              |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     +−>|   (object)   |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     |  | aa: "string" |
                     |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                     |
thisWorks: Ref11232−−+
```

Then you wait for `get` to complete, and print them out.

Comment: Now I must say this is some tough work being put in an answer here

Comment: @ankitbug94: :-) Explaining object references is like a passion of mine. They're so easy to misunderstand, but once you understand them, you're set for life (er, in programming with objects terms).

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
notWorks = {}
```

You are creating a new object and assigning it to `notWorks` but `thisWorks` is still the reference to the previous object that is why the outputs are different

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't really affect the object when the line `notWorks = {}` is executed, you only remove the reference to it from notWorks. thisWorks still points to the same object in memory.